# What is the four tonic system?

Tags: theory, harmony, jazz

What is the four tonic system? What's the theory behind it? How is it used in improvisation, harmonization, reharmonization?

Comment: See also Robert Bailey's notion of the "double tonic complex," where two tonics, typically a third amount equally control a span of music.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*4-tonic system* -- not to be confused with the Teutonic system -- means that a piece of music emphasizes four notes, usually equal intervals apart (in other words a diminished 7th), as its tonic centers.  The chords and melodies generally related to those four tonal centers.

[Coltrane's *Giant Steps*](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2kotK9FNEYU) is a popular example of *3-tonic*, leaping amid G, B, and Eb.

These don't have to be unequal divisions of the polychromatic scale, but that's pretty commonly what these terms are used to refer to in Jazz.

The best example of 4-tonic in a diminished scale which comes to mind to link to is [Egg's *Contrasong*](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h_OZLRS8rS4), which jumps around on these centers.  Also, King Crimson's [*Larks' Tongues in Aspic Part One*](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L0e2HcZAg_Q) has some of this beginning at around the 2:50 point.